# GA Event Track Embedded Form Widget

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-analytics, widget

I have a line of javascript on my webpage, this embeds a simple form widget (`input` box and `search` button). When users enter a value in the input and press enter or `search` they are taken to an external webpage displaying results. This all works as expected.

I'd like to send a custom event to Google Analytics each time a user completes a search.

The GA custom event code I have is;

```
ga('send', 'event', 'search', 'Search Catalogue');
```

I'm not sure what I should do with this code, or where to put it. I have other GA custom event code on my site that works, so I know GA is configured correctly.

When I inspect my webpage the code is as follows;

```
<form method="get" id="searchform" action="https://example.com/search/" target="_parent">
    <input type="text" id="search-query" name="q" value="">
    <button type="submit">Search</button>
</form>
```

I'm open to using either Javascript or Jquery for this.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following code on your page **after** your form has been created;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('body').on('submit','#searchform',function(e) {
            ga('send', 'event', 'search', 'Search Catalogue');
        });
</script>
```

More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002615/how-to-track-a-google-analytics-custom-event-on-an-embedded-form).